# Modelling code base sets

Tags: c#, static, code-analysis

I'm trying to map out code bases in C#. Its quite a complex project where I am keen to pull out aspects such as execution flow, relation between classes. What are the best tools to do this? This is a huge code-set, so I'm keen to try and keep things simple. For example there are lots of derived class types and lots of types.

Is there anything free and powerful enough that would produce something graphical?

here are some aspects we would like:

Block diagrams (How classes are called).
Interdependence.
Method calls.

Answer (score 0):

The architectural view 'Project Dependencies' in ReSharper provides a dynamic interactive view of various inter-project relationships. 
Visual studio Ultimate has 'Dependency Graph Generation'. Also, check out 'Code map', I am not sure though if it is exclusive to VS Ultimate or not.
Otherwise, I am sure there are open source tools, or VS extensions out there that might help.

It would help if you could be more precise exactly what aspects you are interested in pulling out.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012 professional - so I don't think code map exists for this version?

Answer (score 0):

For a large code base, you probably want to start out with an analysis at project/assembly level and type level.
If you incorporate information about methods and their content (e.g. which types are used), you probably want to aggregate that to class or project level.

For .NET, it tends to be more convenient to do this from compiled assembly code, so you probably want to try and compile your code before doing the analysis.  A well-known tool for doing class diagrams and a lot of custom analysis that I've used is [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/), but there are alternatives, e.g. [Lattix](http://lattix.com/).

Code metrics tools, which can measure things about the code, can also be useful, especially when you're looking at the quality of coding or architecture.  Sometimes bad or tangled code sticks out because the size or complexity metrics of the files in question go through the roof.
These tools usually work on source code.  One that I like because it's free and simple is [SourceMonitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html).

Another type of analysis you may be interested in is code duplication analysis.  I used to use [CCFinderX](http://www.ccfinder.net/), mainly for its great visualization, but development ceased and there are plenty of alternatives.

I also wrote a whole batch of utilities to do custom analysis, e.. to check consistency in the solution and project organization (answering questions such as: is every project used in a solution? do assembly dependencies exist that look like they should be project dependencies instead? do we have solutions or projects that look like throwaways, containing duplicated matter from other solutions/projects? can we already see code duplication just by looking at filenames?) . I'm not aware of tools that do this but no doubt they exist.

All of this can give you plenty of information. Looking at program flow is much harder and not very likely to get you anywhere.